# Which USB distributions may fit as notebook/development/demonstration platforms?

Tags: distribution-choice

I want to build a (very) nomad work platform and I don't want it to be on the cloud but on a USB drive. (I know I will have to create backups and/or disk images to make it USB disk failure proof.)

I am very fond of [Dokuwiki on a stick](https://www.dokuwiki.org/install:dokuwiki_on_a_stick) as a portable notebook: it's a Dokuwiki install with a micro-Apache server, and it lets me have my research notes and papers and work on it everywere.

But I would also like to work on my LaTeX papers, on my IPython notebooks, and why not embed my IPython notebooks in my dokuwiki pages. I would then have (nearly) everything I need to work properly and make demos anywhere without bothering with configurations. And even make several USB images for several contexts.

I am then looking for a lightweight live distribution where I can easily install this environment. I know Debian more than other distributions but I'm ready to try any good alternative.

Comment: Typically the answer to these questions is to download one, try it, rinse and repeat until you find one that works for you.

Comment: Indeed. Aside from that you could give this a shot: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/. It gives a wide variety of distro-choices and allows for allocation for persistend memory. I got an archBang installation on a 32GB stick and am very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/) for this. ([Precise Puppy](http://puppylinux.org/main/Long-Term-Supported%20Puppy.htm))

It is very USB stick friendly:

- It loads your save file to RAM on boot.
- It saves your data at an interval (I set it to 30 minutes) and on shutdown to your USB stick.
- Additions are partially done via layered file systems.

This reduces the writes to your USB stick, so that it lasts longer.